# Is it possible to round an integer number to thousands in Oracle?

Tags: oracle11g

For example, if I have the number 7900 then I wanna get the number 8000 as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much from Oracle, but have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm
There you can see, that you can round a DUAL to ten's with

```
    SELECT ROUND(15.193,-1) "Round" FROM DUAL;

     Round
----------
        20
```

So I suppose that you can do this with a -3 and integer in the way you want it.